# analytically calculate the inverse of $4^{th}$ order polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials

There was a quiz test:
Question:
which is the inverse polynomial of  $( X^4 + X + 1)$ ?

a) $(X^3 + X + 1)$

b) $(X^4 + X + 1)$

c) $(X^4 + X^2 + 1)$

d) $(X^4 + X^3 + 1)$

e) the correct answer is missing

and the correct answer was (d).

Could you please show me the steps how to find this inverse function?

[question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jLMBC.jpg)

[keys](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bibjW.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried multiplying the given answer with your polynomial?^^

Comment: @nauok . Would you mind to write clearly (in your question, not in comments) your definition of the "inverse of a polynomial". If not I am afraid that the downvotes will pour down.

Comment: @JJacquelin I edited it. is there a way you can suggest?

Comment: You must have misunderstood (or misreproduced) the homework. The functional inverse of the given polynomial is not a polynomial (in fact, it is not invertible).

Comment: It's not a homework, i've just written the original question. as i mentioned it was a quiz. now i have the correct answer and i want to understand how (d) is correct. is there numerical approach?

Comment: What is the exact wording of the quiz? Please note that there is something called [reciprocal polynomial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reciprocal_polynomial) (or reflected polynomial) which have nothing to do with inverse of a polynomial...

Comment: @nauok: this doesn't make sense, there is information you don't give us.

Comment: believe me it's the exact question with no changes. and i chose (e) as the correct answer on quiz day. but the correct answer is (d).

Comment: Give us more context about the quiz.

Comment: I've added snapshots of the question and its answer. which provided by our TA.

Comment: @nauok. You have not answer to the question "What is the definition of an inverse polynomial". Of course this is not written in the wording of the quiz. But the real object of the quiz is to check if you know what an "inverse polynomial" is in the context of your training. (Because they are several different definitions of "inverse" depending of the context). If you don't know what means a word used in the quiz you cannot correctly answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice that

$$X^4\left(\left(\frac1X\right)^4+\left(\frac1X\right)+1\right)=X^4+X^3+1$$

and that in GF(2), the additive inverse of

$$X^4+X+1$$ is itself.

Comment: Thank you. so all i had to do was to factor x^4 out?

Comment: I don't think you understood my answer. It shows that with crazy interpretations, b) or d) hold.

Comment: AH. OK. i give up.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps there is some mis-understanding.  The inverse of the function $y=x^4+x+1$ is $x$ as a function of $y$ and that is a complicated multi-valued $4$-cycled algebraic function in terms of $y^\frac{1}{4}$.  You can get some idea of it's complexity by simply solving for the inverse in Mathematica via the command:

Solve[y==x^4+x+1,x]

Also, we can numerically invert it by (numerically) solving the associated monodromy differential equation.  To get some idea of what that involves see, [Algebraic Functions](http://jujusdiaries.com)